# Find control in loginview

Tags: c#, asp.net, loginview

[image]I have a masterpage with a loginview, in the loginview i have an asp login control. i also have a label that is NOT contained in a loginview.

How do i access the username textbox control in the asp login control and display the text in a label.

Please help!

This is my code:

```
Login lg = (Login)LoginView1.FindControl("Login1");
TextBox tb = (TextBox)lg.FindControl("UserName");

Label2.Text = tb.Text;
```

ok this is what i need to do: A complainant can deactivate his account. A manager and technicians accounts are deactivated and if necessary also reactivated  by the administrator. the complainant can reactivate his account at any time.

i need to validate the username entered in the textbox to first check if it is an active user. if not it allows them to reactivate it. how do i access the text from the username textbox. the rest i can figure out.

Comment: Can you post the markup for the loginview?

Comment: That should work, what errors do you get?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Maybe you must check if the user is authenticated or not, because the TextBox is inside the [AnonymousTemplate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.loginview.anonymoustemplate.aspx) or it's a Namespace issue(`WebControls.Login`):

```
if (!HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated) {
   Login lg = (WebControls.Login)LoginView1.FindControl("Login1");
   TextBox tb = (TextBox)lg.FindControl("UserName");
   Label2.Text = tb.Text;
}
```

But normally you would get the UserName/Password via the appropriate properties [UserName](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.login.username.aspx)/[Password](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.login.password.aspx) of the `Login`.

**Edit**: Your added screenshot is very small but i see that you are getting an InvalidCastException, so my asumption on the namespace issue was correct.

Comment: I assume that your have another class "Login", that causes a namespace conflict. You want to cast it to `WebControls.Login`.

Comment: the error is: Unable to cast object of type 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.Login' to type 'Gui.Login'. I only have 1 login control in the entire application

Comment: @Kuven: Have you seen that i've edited my answer and what i've modified? `Login lg = (WebControls.Login)LoginView1.FindControl("Login1");`
The login-control is of type `WebControls.Login` and not `Gui.Login` what might be an aspx-codebehind class or whatelse.

Comment: do i have to include any other using clause because WebControls is giving an error. type or namespace not found

Comment: The full path is `System.Web.UI.WebControls.Login`