# How do I manipulate the text in my Site.Master file in codebehind

Tags: c#, asp.net, authentication, code-behind, master-pages

I would like to carry out some string operations on the username in my Site.Master page before rendering it on the page.

Here's what the current code looks like:

```
<div class="login">
    <asp:LoginView ID="HeadLoginView" runat="server" EnableViewState="false">
         <LoggedInTemplate>
             Welcome <span class="bold"><asp:LoginName ID="HeadLoginName" runat="server" /></span>
         </LoggedInTemplate>
    </asp:LoginView>
</div>
```

For some reason, I cannot reference HeadLoginName.Text or something similar. What am I missing here?

Thanks for looking.

Comment: HeadLoginName is a control in a template. It's essentially a child of the login control. You need to do a Find() for the HeadLoginName control in the loginview control.

Comment: Are sure that you're writing this code in the master page .cs file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Possible Duplicate:**

[Find control in loginview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7769554/find-control-in-loginview)

It is necessary to find the "HeadLoginName" control inside the "HeadLoginView" container first and then specify its Text property (see the [Find Control with in LoginView control](http://weblogs.asp.net/sukumarraju/archive/2011/01/31/find-control-with-in-loginview-control.aspx) blog post for more information):

```
LoginName ln = (LoginName)HeadLoginView.FindControl("HeadLoginName");
ln.Text = ...;
```