# Findcontrol Textbox inside Login, inside LoginView

Tags: .net, vb.net

I have a couple textboxes inside of a Login control, which is inside a LoginView. How can I use findcontrol to get the textboxes? The following does not work: get error: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

```
Dim UName As TextBox = CType(LoginView1.FindControl("Login1").FindControl("UserName"), TextBox)

Or

Dim Logins As Login = CType(LoginView1.FindControl("Login1"), Login)
    Dim UName As TextBox = CType(Logins.FindControl("UserName"), TextBox)
```

aspx

```
<asp:LoginView ID="LoginView1" runat="server">
            <LoggedInTemplate>
                <div class="logged">                        
                    <ul class="Logged">
                        <li><asp:LoginStatus ID="LoginStatus1" Font-Size="Small" LogoutPageUrl="http://NCOASouth.com" LogoutAction="Redirect" runat="server" /></li>
                        <li><asp:HyperLink ID="AdminLink" Visible="false" runat="server" NavigateUrl="~/Admin/Default.aspx" Text="Administration"></asp:HyperLink></li>
                        <li>Welcome, <asp:LoginName ID="LoginName1" runat="server" />!</li>

                    </ul>
                </div>


            </LoggedInTemplate>
            <AnonymousTemplate>
                <h2 class="title1">Officials Login</h2>             
                    <br /><br /><br />
                    <asp:Login ID="Login1" DestinationPageUrl="http://NCOASouth.com/redirect.aspx"
                                CreateUserText="create new account" CreateUserUrl="~/Register.aspx" runat="server">
                                <LayoutTemplate>
                                    <asp:TextBox ID="UserName" CssClass="textbox" runat="server" Width="195px" placeholder="Username"></asp:TextBox><br />
                                    <asp:TextBox ID="Password" CssClass="textbox" runat="server" TextMode="Password" Width="195px" placeholder="Password"></asp:TextBox><br /><br />
                                    <asp:Button ID="LoginButton" ValidationGroup="ctl00$Login1" CssClass="textbox" runat="server" CommandName="Login" Width="200px" Text="Sign In"/>
                                    <br /><br />
                                    <asp:HyperLink ID="createnewuser" runat="server" NavigateUrl="~/Register.aspx" Text="Register for Free" /><br />
                                    <asp:HyperLink ID="forgotpassword" runat="server" NavigateUrl="~/forgotPassword.aspx" Text="Forgot Password" />

                                    <asp:Literal ID="FailureText" runat="server" EnableViewState="False"></asp:Literal>
                                    <br />
                                    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="UserNameRequired" runat="server"
                                        ControlToValidate="UserName" ErrorMessage="User Name is required."
                                        ToolTip="User Name is required." ValidationGroup="ctl00$Login1"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                                    <br />
                                    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="PasswordRequired" runat="server"
                                        ControlToValidate="Password" ErrorMessage="Password is required."
                                        ToolTip="Password is required." ValidationGroup="ctl00$Login1"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                                </LayoutTemplate>
                            </asp:Login>
            </AnonymousTemplate>
        </asp:LoginView>
```

Comment: http://go4answers.webhost4life.com/Example/login-control-controls-not-exist-83064.aspx... Yoiu will find the solution here..

Comment: show your aspx code please.

Comment: @UpvoteMarkAnswer not sure which one of the 17 answers on that page applies

Comment: possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7769554/find-control-in-loginview

Comment: slfan you are right that duplicate answered my question..thanks for pointing me to that solution