# Findcontrol for Login inside LoginView

Tags: .net, vb.net

I can't get the Username textbox in a Login Control inside a LoginView. Its telling me UName "Object not set to an instance of an object"

```
Dim UName As TextBox = CType(LoginView1.FindControl("Login1").FindControl("UserName"), TextBox)
```

aspx

```
<asp:LoginView ID="LoginView1" runat="server">
            <LoggedInTemplate>
                <div class="logged">                        
                    <ul class="Logged">
                        <li><asp:LoginStatus ID="LoginStatus1" Font-Size="Small" LogoutPageUrl="http://NCOASouth.com" LogoutAction="Redirect" runat="server" /></li>
                        <li><asp:HyperLink ID="AdminLink" Visible="false" runat="server" NavigateUrl="~/Admin/Default.aspx" Text="Administration"></asp:HyperLink></li>
                        <li>Welcome, <asp:LoginName ID="LoginName1" runat="server" />!</li>

                    </ul>
                </div>


            </LoggedInTemplate>
            <AnonymousTemplate>
                <h2 class="title1">Officials Login</h2>             
                    <br /><br /><br />
                    <asp:Login ID="Login1" DestinationPageUrl="http://NCOASouth.com/redirect.aspx"
                                CreateUserText="create new account" CreateUserUrl="~/Register.aspx" runat="server">
                                <LayoutTemplate>
                                    <asp:TextBox ID="UserName" CssClass="textbox" runat="server" Width="195px" placeholder="Username"></asp:TextBox><br />
                                    <asp:TextBox ID="Password" CssClass="textbox" runat="server" TextMode="Password" Width="195px" placeholder="Password"></asp:TextBox><br /><br />
                                    <asp:Button ID="LoginButton" ValidationGroup="ctl00$Login1" CssClass="textbox" runat="server" CommandName="Login" Width="200px" Text="Sign In"/>
                                    <br /><br />
                                    <asp:HyperLink ID="createnewuser" runat="server" NavigateUrl="~/Register.aspx" Text="Register for Free" /><br />
                                    <asp:HyperLink ID="forgotpassword" runat="server" NavigateUrl="~/forgotPassword.aspx" Text="Forgot Password" />

                                    <asp:Literal ID="FailureText" runat="server" EnableViewState="False"></asp:Literal>
                                    <br />
                                    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="UserNameRequired" runat="server"
                                        ControlToValidate="UserName" ErrorMessage="User Name is required."
                                        ToolTip="User Name is required." ValidationGroup="ctl00$Login1"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                                    <br />
                                    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="PasswordRequired" runat="server"
                                        ControlToValidate="Password" ErrorMessage="Password is required."
                                        ToolTip="Password is required." ValidationGroup="ctl00$Login1"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                                </LayoutTemplate>
                            </asp:Login>
            </AnonymousTemplate>
        </asp:LoginView>
```

Comment: This is a duplicate, and answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7769554/find-control-in-loginview

Answer (score 0):

This is in C#, but you could use something similar to this in order to find your control:

http://weblogs.asp.net/eporter/archive/2007/02/24/asp-net-findcontrol-recursive-with-generics.aspx

In general, `FindControl` is rarely useful unless you only want to go one layer deep.

**EDIT:**

From the link provided:

```
public static T FindControl<T>(System.Web.UI.ControlCollection Controls, string ControlName) where T : class
{
     T found = default(T);

     if (Controls != null && Controls.Count > 0)
     {
          for (int i = 0; i < Controls.Count; i++)
          {
               if (Controls[i] is T && Controls[i].ID == ControlName)
               {
                    found = Controls[i] as T;
                    break;
               }
               else
                    found = FindControl<T>(Controls[i].Controls);
          }
     }

     return found;
}
```

And in your case, you would use (in C#):

```
var uName = FindControl<TextBox>(LoginView1.Controls, "UserName");
```

The generics usage in VB.NET is not something I'm very familiar with.  You could remove the generics portion of this and just use `Control.`

Comment: Because your control is nested in the template, and not a direct descendant. A recursive search will start at whatever point in the control tree you specify then search down until it finds a matching control. Find control isn't as friendly/intelligent.